# What does "la" refer to in the expression "Non te la prendere con me"?

Tags: meaning

> Non te **la** prendere con me.

Q1) Given the meaning of the phrase, "take it out on", I wonder if "la" stands for "la rivincita" in "prendersi la rivincita". I'm assuming this is an equivalent of the French expression "s'**en** prendre à".

Q2) In French, "s'en prendre à" can refer to either **verbally** taking it/your frustration out on someone or attacking/harming them **physically**. In Italian, is this expression confined to verbal abuse, or can it extend to physical violence?

Answer (score 2):

***[Prendersela](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/prendersela)*** (con qualcuno e/o per qualcosa) è un’espressione idiomatica che significa:

> 1. ***offendersi***, mostrarsi offeso per qcs.: *non prendertela per così poco*
> 2. avere un atteggiamento d’ira o risentimento, ***arrabbiarsi***: *te la prendi sempre con lui*.

(De Mauro)

Come dice [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prendere/) la particella pronominale LA puo far riferimento a vari contesti, in questo caso si riferisce alla situazione che può generare arrabbiature o risentimenti:

> ***Con il pronome la indeterminato***: ***prenderla in mala parte***, non com., considerare come ostili o offensivi atti e detti di altra persona (e al contr., prenderla in buona parte); ***prenderla bene o male***, reagire bene o male a un fatto (e analogam., non so come la prenderà, quali saranno le sue reazioni); ***prendersela calda***, accalorarsi, accendersi in qualche cosa, parteciparvi con eccessivo calore; assol., ***prendersela, aversene a male, dispiacersi di qualche cosa*** (non te la prendere, non t’inquietare o addolorare), o anche far pesare ad altri, scaricare su altri il proprio risentimento: se non sei riuscito non puoi prendertela con me; cerca sempre qualcuno con cui prendersela; ***meno com. in questo senso il semplice prenderla***: *con sua signoria illustrissima non la può prendere, che è un pezzo molto più grosso di lui (Manzoni)*.

Comment: Since the OP has explicitly said that [he/she feels more comfortable with answers in English](https://italian.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/20936), may someone **add** (I think there is no need to delete this Italian version) a translation or a similar explanation in English?